# Symetric matrix with non-negative entries has an eigenvalue with non-negative coordinates.

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory, self-adjoint-operators

> Let $M \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ symetric with $[M]_{ij} \geq 0$. Prove that $M$ has an eigenvector $(v_1,...,v_n)$ with $v_i \geq 0$.

This question is from my exercise list about Spectral Theory of Self-Adjoint and Normal Maps. My problem is: I really don't know how to approach that question using this theory. So, I don't want a solution, I think some hints are enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$M$ has $n$ orthogonal unit eigenvectors $e_i$ for eigenvalues
$\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2\ge \cdots \ge\lambda_n$.  For a unit vector $v=\sum \alpha_i e_i$ we have
$$\langle A v, v\rangle = \sum |\alpha_i|^2 \lambda_i$$
Therefore, the maximum value of $\langle A v, v\rangle$ on the unit sphere is attained only for an eigenvector for value $\lambda_1$

Now note that for $v$ unit vector, the vector $w$ with components the absolute value of the components of $v$ is also unit and $\langle A w, w\rangle \ge \langle A v, v\rangle$.

Comment: If I understood, $w$ is in the unit sphere and so, $\langle Aw, w \rangle$ must be the maximum of $\langle Av,v \rangle$ in the unit sphere, that is, $w$ must be an eigenvector associate to $\lambda_1$.

Comment: This ideia seems similar to Rayleigh quotient for self-adjoint maps.

Comment: @Greg: Yes, it is enough to get the largest value on the sphere, attained for a positive entry vector, and check that it is an eigenvector, like in the theory

Comment: Shouldn't it be $|\alpha_i|^2$ since $\alpha_i\in\mathbb C$?

Comment: @Matija: Yes, indeed!  Will correct it right away, thank you!